# React passing information to multiple child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

My application has a bunch of child components `Card` that are used to display different information. When user input changes, some `Card`s are required to highlight themselves / show a warning / etc. These inputs can happen pretty much anywhere, from an input bar to hovering on a `Card`, etc.

To decouple, My current design is to use a `Context` containing a dictionary from `Card`'s id -> a custom object storing display states. Then, I create multiple callback functions in my `App` that subcomponents can call, and changes the dictionary respectively. In code:

```js
// App.ts
export const CardCtx = createContext({});
function App() {
    const [cardStates, setCardStates] = useState<Record<string, CardState>>({}); // dict in typescript
    
    // callback functions for children components.
    // function1 and 2 are defined elsewhere to avoid large App()
    const handleInput = (args) => { function1(args, cardStates, setCardStates) };
    const handleHover = (args) => { function2(args, cardStates, setCardStates) };

    return (
        <CardCtx.Provider>
            <Component1 callback={handleInput} /> // contains some Cards
            <Component2 callback={handleHover} /> // contains other Cards, etc...
        </CardCtx.Provider>
    )
}
```

And then in `Card` component:

```js
// Card.ts, imports omitted
function Card({cardInfo}) { // info passed in by props
    const cardStates = useContext(CardCtx); // ctx imported from App.ts
    return (...); // handle css style based on cardStates[cardInfo.id]
}
```

Current problems I have are:

- React has bad support on using complex types as state variables. To avoid multiple callbacks trying to change the dictionary before the next render, I need to force `flushSync()` in every callback, which is bad :(
- A huge amount of callback functions are piled up in my `App`. To avoid large chunks of code, I am defining functions elsewhere and wrapping callback functions around them (see above code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> React has bad support on using complex types as state variables. To avoid multiple callbacks trying to change the dictionary before the next render, I need to force flushSync() in every callback, which is bad.

You can use Reducer instead of a complex state variable, and here is an example of a CardReducer  that  you can you can take the original state (that will have all other types of cards) and change only the warning state.

```
export const CardContext = createContext(null);

function cardReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_WARNING':
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.cardId]: {
          ...state[action.cardId],
          warning: true
        }
      };
    case 'CLEAR_WARNING':
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.cardId]: {
          ...state[action.cardId],
          warning: false
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and make the original state of the reducer and provide them through the value prop in the CardContext.Provider component in the app as follows:

```
function App() {
  const [cardState, dispatch] = useReducer(cardReducer, {});

  return (
    <CardContext.Provider value={{ cardState, dispatch }}>
      <Component1 />
      <Component2 />
    </CardContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

and to use it in the Card component you can do the following:

```
function Card({ cardInfo }) {
  const { cardState, dispatch } = useContext(CardContext);

  const handleInput = (args) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_WARNING',
      cardId: cardInfo.id
    });
  };

  const handleHover = (args) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'CLEAR_WARNING',
      cardId: cardInfo.id
    });
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={cardState[cardInfo.id]?.warning ? 'card warning' : 'card'}
      onMouseEnter={handleHover}
      onMouseLeave={handleHover}
    >
      {cardInfo.content}
    </div>
  );
}
```

> A huge amount of callback functions are piled up in my App. To avoid large chunks of code, I am defining functions elsewhere and wrapping callback functions around them.

To solve this issue, you can make a custom hook card actions component, that will have all possible callback functions that you need in your application. You then get import the callbacks from that component when needed in any other component.

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { CardContext } from './App';

export default function useCardActions(cardId) {
  const { dispatch } = useContext(CardContext);

  const setWarning = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_WARNING',
      cardId
    });
  };

  const clearWarning = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'CLEAR_WARNING',
      cardId
    });
  };

  return {
    setWarning,
    clearWarning
  };
}
```

and you can use the callbacks that you defined in the card component as follows:

```
import useCardActions from './useCardActions';

function Card({ cardInfo }) {
  const { cardState } = useContext(CardContext);
  const { setWarning, clearWarning } = useCardActions(cardInfo.id);

  return (
    <div
      className={cardState[cardInfo.id]?.warning ? 'card warning' : 'card'}
      onMouseEnter={setWarning}
      onMouseLeave={clearWarning}
    >
      {cardInfo.content}
    </div>
  );
}
```

By doing so, you will avoid defining multiple callbacks in the App component and it will look cleaner and easy to understand.

I hope this helps and if you still have any questions, I am more than happy to help.